# How to remove /blogs from url shopify blog pages?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am working on shopify theme. And i want to remove /blogs from some ingle pages.I didnt't find any solution from shopify support or forum nor from google. How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.
URL structures are predefined on Shopify and can't be modified.

Comment: Did you check shopify website blog url? https://www.shopify.com/blog